# Accessing Guest outlook.office365.com mailbox via IMAP- Authenticate Failed Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have followed all steps to use client credentials grant flow to authenticate IMAP.

1. Registered my app on Azure AD (multitenant)
2. Set App permissions (Screenshot attached)
3. Set Service Principals
4. Acquiring token with scope- "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" and doing post- [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

I do get the token but it throws "NO AUTHENTICATE FAILED" error.

Here's the issue- The app was created and permissions set using TESTDOMAIN1 account. So it works/authenticates without any problems for emails with abc@TESTDOMAIN1.com.
But if I try to access a guest account(account added in Azure using invitation) like xyz@TESTDOMAIN2.com, it generates the token but throws NO AUTHENTICATE FAILED error.

I tried updating the service principal as well to access this emailbox but I got error there too. (Screenshot attached)

Please suggest if I'm missing something here. All I want to do is access any of my users (Azure AD Users or external users) to access my app and be able to use the api and give access to mailbox.

[ApiPermissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE7W7.png)
[GuestAccount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeX10.png)
[ServicePrincipalError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Whsz.png)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD application and added permission like below:

[image]

***I generated the authorization code with below parameters.***

```json
GET 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=e626f30a-80ea-4530-81e9-ebxxxxx
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

***I generated access token successfully like below.***

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token 
 
grant_type:authorization_code  
client_id:e626f30a-80ea-4530-81e9-ebxxxxx
client_secret:client_secret  
scope://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms 
code:code
```

[image]